# Failed to parse time string with name of the day before the date

Tags: php, html, datetime

I have a field in my database which represents the day. But if I try to parse it to a DateTime I get the following error:

```
Failed to parse time string (tuesday, 18 april 2017) at position 0 (d): The timezone could not be found in the database
```

Now I parse the data further by stripping the day (number of the day) and the month (number of the month) by doing this:

```
$stripDay = $createDate->format('d');
$stripMonth = $createDate->format('M');
```

But now I get the error stated above. I think it has something to do with the day that is put before the date (tuesday in this example). Do I need to convert the time first so that the day is cut off?

EDIT: My string to begin with is this: tuesday, 18 april 2017

I need to convert it to a date first I presume before I can make changes to it, but I cannot seem to convert it. because if I use `$createDate1 = new DateTime($date);` I get an error

Comment: 16 april 2017 is sunday not tuesday ????

Comment: Sorry was a typo. I identified the problem. It's because the original string (tuesday, 18 april 2017) is in dutch (dinsdag, 18 april 2017)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use :

```
$stripDay = date('d',strtotime('tuesday, 18 april 2017'));
$stripMonth = date('m',strtotime('tuesday, 18 april 2017'));
```

my test:

```
echo $stripDay ;
```

it print 18

Comment: Does not work, gives me 1's back for month but also day. Also I cannot create a DateTime because it gives me the error stated above: $createDate = new DateTime($date);

Comment: print your date here

Comment: Above data gives me 1's back again.

Comment: OK i identified the problem!! Because my strings are in Dutch, the moment I insert the dutch date into the date field it gives me 1's back. Is there some command to change the date to english, or change the date to dutch

Comment: That is another question though, I marked your answer as correct and I will search for a solution for the Dutch date language conversion

Answer (score 2):

you can use date php.net/manual/en/function.date.php to get the format of a string rather nicely:

```
$date = '2017-01-01 11:11:11';

$day    = date('d', strtotime($date));
$month  = date('m', strtotime($date));
$year   = date('Y', strtotime($date));
$hour   = date('H', strtotime($date));
$minute = date('i', strtotime($date));
$second = date('s', strtotime($date));
```

Comment: Does not work, gives me 1's back for month but also day

Comment: @HuubS please print your $date here

Comment: See my edit above. My $date is tuesday, 18 april 2017